# How to call Pyramid server from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, pyramid

I have used pyramid to write a project. In a html page of the project, i want to use a button to call a python script, the python script is located in the path "myapp/Script".

I have this method tried but it dosn't work:

```
<script Language="javascript">
    function call() {
        http://localhost/Scripts/xxx.py
    }
</script>
```

Thank you very much!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most scenarios, the communicating from JavaScript to server-side is done using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX). Furthermore, most sites use [jQuery JavaScript library to make AJAX programming easier](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

AJAX requests are handled like any other HTTP requests in Pyramid.

1. [Write a view in Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki/definingviews.html) (this is the "python script" part)
2. [Map this view to URL](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/urldispatch.html)
3. [Include jQuery library on your HTML page](http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn)
4. Then call it through AJAX

   ```
   <script>
       function call() {
           $.ajax("/myurl/", function(result) {
               console.log("I got this response from the server ", result)
           });
       }
   </script>
   ```